# "unrecognized feature:'attribution-reporting'" from Google Tag Manager causing drop in ad conversions for Facebook and Google

Tags: google, google-adsense, facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-ads-manager

I'm seeing 1 warning from the `gtm.js` library in Chrome browser console which could be related to this issue but I didn't find any information about them online.This is the error message:

`unrecognized feature:'attribution-reporting'`

Does anyone know anything about it? The tags are Fine.